# Set tapping instead of clicking for Arch Mouse

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mouse, preferences, click

I am looking for a way to TAP the arch mouse and NOT click the mouse button for the same clicking action. I am using a MacBook Pro 2017.

I go to System Preferences -> Microsoft Mouse and there is no option to replace clicking for tapping.  My index finger is taking a toll every time I click the left mouse button.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Just asking a clear question is best. You can always thank someone later if needed more than a check mark or up vote.

Comment: Perhaps you need to install some 3rd party application that came with the mouse?